# Extracting email service provider from String in Python

Tags: python, string

I would like extract the email service provider from the user input, below code is giving me no error but there is no result as well.

Appreciate if someone can review and let me know what I am doing wrong?

Code :

```
getEmail = input("Write your email: ")

email = getEmail.index('@')

print(getEmail[:email])
print("Your user name is : " + getEmail[:email])
print("Your Email service provider is : " + getEmail[getEmail.index('@'):getEmail.index('.')])
```

Output

```
Write your email: nick.fury@gmail.com
nick.fury
Your user name is : nick.fury
Your Email service provider is :
```

expected result

Your user name is : nick.fury

Your Email service provider is : gmail

Comment: What does `getEmail.index(".")` output? What if you try `nfury@gmail.com`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe `getEmail.index(".")` in this case returns 4 (first index of '.'). If you use an example as you proposed it will work, but still code will not work properly for all emails with '.' in use name part.

Comment: @Relandom *I* know that; it's a rhetorical question intended to guide the OP to solving the problem themselves.

Comment: oh... Sorry, I thought that you advise changing code rather than code. My bad!

Comment: The domain part of the email address is not necessarily directly indicative of the provider. You can't know if `user@x.y.example` is in a subdomain of `y.example` or if that's an administrative domain of the `example` TLD (compare `mail.google.ca` vs `mail.google.co.uk` etc and try to disregard whatever semantics we humans read into those labels).

Answer (score 0):

This part: `getEmail[getEmail.index('@'):getEmail.index('.')])` is not working because `getEmail.index('@')` is bigger than `getEmail.index('.')]`.
`getEmail.index('.')]` return FIRST index of '.'
You can try this approach:

```
getEmail = input("Write your email: ")

email, domain = getEmail.split('@')

print(email)
print("Your user name is: " + email)
print("Your Email service provider is: " + domain.split('.')[0])
```

Also while using `print` method you don't have to use `+`. You can use `,`:
`print("Your user name is:", email)`

Answer (score 0):

```
getEmail = input("Write your email: ")
email = getEmail.index('@')
print("Your user name is : " + getEmail[:email])
print("Your Email service provider is : " + getEmail[getEmail.index('@')+1:][:getEmail.index('.')-1])
```

Output :

Write your email: asfdsf.asd@gmail.com

Your user name is : asfdsf.asd

Your Email service provider is : gmail

Answer (score 0):

Assuming well-formed input, a much simpler approach is

```
get_email = input("User email: ")
username, hostname = get_email.split('@')
provider = hostname.split('.')[0]
```

Answer (score -1):

Code:

```
getEmail = input("Write your email: ")

email = getEmail.index('@')
provider = getEmail[email+1:]

print(getEmail[:email])
print("Your user name is : " + getEmail[:email])
print("Your Email service provider is : " + provider[:provider.index('.')])
```

Output:

```
Write your email: nick.fury@gmail.com
nick.fury
Your user name is : nick.fury
Your Email service provider is : gmail
```